# Sorting an array with a repeating element (given its frequency) in linear time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, runtime

Assume we have an array with n integers and we know that some integer x, appears alpha times in the array. Prove or disprove that exists an algorithm that can sort this array in linear time for:

[image]

So all I've seen in class about this subject is count-sort and radix-sort which both assume something about the range of the numbers in the array and not about the amount of repetition. This leads me to think that I can always find some integer big enough that would disprove the possibility of finding a linear sorting algorithm. On the other hand, I don't even know where to start disproving this formally so either I'm wrong or I'm missing something. I would love some help in proving this formally.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allow something like radix sort and consider it linear time, the question is meaningless. So it's about ordinary [comparison sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort), which generally can be done in O(n log n) but not O(n), making the question meaningful.

#### α<sub>1</sub>:

Linear is possible. There are n^(9/10) values other than that frequent x. If n≤1024, then sort any reasonable way you like, doesn't matter for big O. If n>1024, then more than half the elements are x. Use [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm?wprov=sfla1) to identify it. Extract the n^(9/10) other values values and mergesort them in n^(9/10) log n^(9/10) = O(n) time. Combine them with the x-values.

#### α<sub>2</sub>:

Linear is not possible. If there were such an algorithm, then you could sort **any** m values in O(m) time by adding one element 9m times, applying that hypothetical algorithm in O(10m) = O(m) time, and removing the duplicates you added.